Aiogram: have a problem with form states in handlers
I've got file main.py with such code:
import asyncio
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.client.default import DefaultBotProperties
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode

import config

from handlers.start import start_router
from handlers.pressure import pressure_router

async def main() -> None:
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.include_routers(
        start_router,
        pressure_router
    )

    bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN, default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))

    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    asyncio.run(main())

And a file pressure.py:
from aiogram import Router
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.types import Message, KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import State, StatesGroup

import datetime
import json
import logging

pressure_router = Router()

class Form(StatesGroup):
    #time_day = ""
    systolic = State()
    diastolic = State()
    pulse = State()

@pressure_router.message(Command("pressure"))
async def command_pressure(message:Message) -> None:
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard= [
            [
                KeyboardButton(text="Ранок"),
                KeyboardButton(text="День"),
                KeyboardButton(text="Вечір"),
                KeyboardButton(text="Таблетки")
            ]
        ],
        resize_keyboard=True,
    )


    await message.answer("Вибери категорію", reply_markup=markup)

@pressure_router.message()
async def get_text(message: Message, state:FSMContext) -> None:
    if message.text == ["Ранок", "День", "Вечір"]:
        #Form.time_day = f"{message.text}"

        await state.set_state(Form.systolic)
        current_state = await state.get_state()
        logging.info(f"Current state: {current_state}")

        await message.bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="Вкажи перше число", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

@pressure_router.message(Form.systolic)
async def get_systolic_pressure(message: Message, state:FSMContext) -> None:
    logging.info(f"get_systolic_pressure: Received message {message.text}")
    await state.update_data(systolic=message.text)

    await message.answer("HELLO!")

When I use the command /pressure it works and show me a message await message.bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text="Вкажи перше число", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()), but when I write a number(for ex. 120), there is nothing work
In logging I've got
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher:Start polling
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher:Run polling for bot @alex_helperuabot id=5834371058 - 'Helper Alex'
INFO:root:Current state: Form:systolic
INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=767330529 is handled. Duration 531 ms by bot id=5834371058
INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=767330530 is handled. Duration 0 ms by bot id=5834371058

When i write a number, duraction is 0 ms and that's all. I was wrtiting the code using the oficial documentation of aiogram, but I have no idea how to fix it.
